# Creating Angular Dart Web Notification

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I started out with an Angular Dart chat tutorial. I want to add a button that pops up a notification on the other chat users desktop - even if they have the browser minimized.

Are "Web Notifications" the right approach? Has anyone developed an Angular2 Dart Web Notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can directly use the Notification api from the `dart:html` package

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-html/Notification-class.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: Thanks - that put me on the right track.  


//        if (!Notification.supported) {
//          await Notification.requestPermission();
          new Notification("Hello world", body: "Have a nice day!");
 //       }else{
 //         print("Notification not supported");
 //       }


The Notification.supported returns false but if I comment that out I do get a notification popup.

Comment: Can't seem to get Notification.supported and Notification.requestPermission to work. In general I can get Notifications to appear in Chrome and Firefox but not Edge or IE 11.  Edge looks like it should work.  IE 11 apparently does not support Notifications. Thanks for putting me on the right track.